# Marklogic Data Hub Configuration Export

Tags: marklogic

How would i export the MarkLogic Data Hub v5.x configuration & all its objects ( like Entities, Flows etc ) to a zip file please?

That way I can clone data hub structure as needed and re-create a copy on multiple servers for parallel testing tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on DHF 5.2.0 or greater, just use the Gradle task "hubExportProject".

Comment: Thanks. One concept I'd like to clear up please - is the data hub just the projects, or is the data hub a shell, but with the projects "installed" inside? It seems the data hub only comes into existance with deployment of your first data hub project? Just trying to clarify this.

Comment: That's correct - DHF scaffolds out a project, and then you deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

When you created your data hub project, that created a bunch of files on the file system. Best practice is to use [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) to deploy that configuration to your other environments. ml-gradle lets you set up environment-specific properties files to manage differences between your environments (such as the host(s) you're deploying to.

Comment: I've just finished working through a 4.1.x to 5.2.x Server & DH upgrade process and wanted to be able to replicate the final config  to other servers for testing.  I will have a read through the ml-gradle info, thanks.

Comment: I get it that the gradle project can be exported this way, but how does this export the data base configurations for the entity model? I'd like to do a similar thing and be able to clone the entity model that I created with DHC 5.5.2 onto another MarkLogic instance. In fact I'd like to understand what all entity model components are created so I can at least back them up and restore from them in case something goes screwy with the DHC entity modeling application.